# Docker UCP Error: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-registry, docker-ucp

I have recently upgraded from `Docker UCP 1.0.3 to 1.1.0 version`.
However, I am getting the following message:

```
   STDOUT:
    STDERR: time="2016-05-09T20:10:31Z" level=info msg="Verifying your system is compatible with UCP"
    time="2016-05-09T20:10:31Z" level=info msg="Your engine version 1.11.1-cs1 is compatible"
    time="2016-05-09T20:10:31Z" level=info msg="All required images are present"
    time="2016-05-09T20:10:31Z" level=info msg="Installing UCP with host address 10.211.130.108 - If this is incorrect, please specify an alternative address with the '--host-address' flag"
    time="2016-05-09T20:10:31Z" level=info msg="Checking that required ports are available and accessible"
    time="2016-05-09T20:10:34Z" level=info msg="Generating UCP Cluster Root CA"
    time="2016-05-09T20:10:51Z" level=info msg="Generating UCP Client Root CA"
    time="2016-05-09T20:10:58Z" level=info msg="Deploying UCP Containers"
    **time="2016-05-09T20:11:01Z" level=error msg="error waiting for KV endpoint to be healthy: Get https://10.211.130.108:12379/health: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of \"crypto/rsa: verification error\" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate \"UCP Cluster Root CA\")"
    time="2016-05-09T20:11:01Z" level=error msg="Failed to start KV store.  Run \"docker logs ucp-kv\" for more details"**
    time="2016-05-09T20:11:01Z" level=fatal msg="Get https://10.211.130.108:12379/health: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of \"crypto/rsa: verification error\" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate \"UCP Cluster Root CA\")"
    ---- End output of docker run --rm -i -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --name ucp docker/ucp:1.1.0 install --host-address 10.211.130.108 ----
    Ran docker run --rm -i -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --name ucp docker/ucp:1.1.0 install --host-address 10.211.130.108 returned 1
```